# Express f(x) as a linear combination of Legendre Polynomials

Tags: legendre-polynomials

I have the following Legendre Polynomials,

$$P_{0}\left(x\right) = 1$$
$$P_{1}\left(x\right) = x$$
$$P_{2}\left(x\right) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(3x^{2}-1\right)$$
$$P_{3}\left(x\right) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(5x^{3}-3x\right)$$
$$P_{4}\left(x\right) = \dfrac{1}{8}\left(35x^{4}-30x^{2}+3\right)$$
$$P_{5}\left(x\right) = \dfrac{1}{8}\left(63x^{5}-70x^{3}+15x\right)$$

Is there a method, that isn't just by inspection, for expressing $f\left(x\right)=x^{3}-5x-2$ as a linear combination of the above Legendre Polynomials?

Comment: Fix the typo in the definition of $f(x)$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [Legendre polynomials are orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Orthogonality) so you can express the coefficient in terms of an integral

$$f(x)=\sum_i \alpha_i P_i(x) \\
\alpha_i = \frac{2 i + 1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 P_i(x) f(x) dx$$